# nhibernate QueryOver not throwing exception when mapping is missing

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Can anyone explain what's the idea behind nHibernate QueryOver not throwing exception when there is no mapping for used class? Let's say i have a FakeClass class and no mapping defined, code below executes without exception.

```
var result =  session.QueryOver<FakeClass>()
                     .Where(x => x.Name == "SomeName").List();
```

Comment: Wouldn't unit testing aid you here. I understand its not the answer you are looking for but a unit test would pick this up.

Comment: thing is it was a bug which was hard to find, actually for ower two weeks i was developing a project which one part was working by accident. unit testing may be the right way to detect this kind of mistakes but i think this kind of test will be no longer called unit  - just automatic ( in my opinion ). Mapping file existed in another assembly and was just nor properly attached to hibernate configuration. Bad behavior suggested that we created a bug in code or configuration and also we didn't use Get which throws exception. so the case is not so simple.

Comment: also i'm disorientated, because if it is a bug in nhibernate that's really really strange that it wasn't found and fixed so far, but if it is not i don't see any benefits of this "feature".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well it's a reported bug: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2829

hope it won't end like this : https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2183

Comment: It's still not fixed. Very annoying bug indeed.

Comment: aaand still not fixed as of 2017 and NH5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Does FakeClass exist as a table in the database? If so, i would  think that Fluent's automapping feature would map to it as designed.

Comment: no there is no fakeclass table.. i have over 15k types in my test domain and only 477 throw exception when used  in expression: session.CreateCriteria(type).List();